# How to move a gameobject in Unity with the click on UI button when otherwise I would need the Update function to check for new inputs?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am having a little trouble understanding the following. I am working on a simple game where the player can move a game object around by clicking left or right on the keyboard. Simple enough:

```
void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftArrow))
    {
        transform.position += Vector3.left * movementSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
    }
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.RightArrow))
    {
        transform.position += Vector3.right * movementSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
    }
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.UpArrow))
    {
        transform.position += Vector3.up * jumpHeight * Time.deltaTime;
    }
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.DownArrow))
    {
        transform.position += Vector3.down * movementSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
    }
}
```

However, I also have two buttons on screen, that are also supposed to move the player just as the keyevents do. What I dont understand is, that I need an update function to check every frame if a new button is pressed, right? So now I have my button and assign a script to it, where I can attach the button to a certain function of that script. But I cannot simply assign the button to a new "update" function that checks for different inputs of that button. How do I get my Ui Button to also controll the player JUST like the Update function does here?

Thank you!

Comment: You should take a look at how the standard assets virtual joystick works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out the [Screenshot of the Scene](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8K02R.png). Just create an UI with an EventSystem. Create a button within your UI. Attach an EventTrigger to your button. Now create two Events on your EventTrigger:
(1) Pointer Down (will be called, when the button get's pressed down.)
(2) Pointer Up (will be called when the button is released.)

Attach the script at the end of this answer as a component to your player or cube or whatever you wanna move.
Now you can see on the screenshot, that the public method MoveCube.MoveLeft get's called whenever the MoveLeftButton is pressed. Whenever it is released, the MoveCube.StopMovingLeft gets called. The joke is about the bool, that will be switched from false to true and back. The actual movement happens in the Update, that essentially follows the same logic as the script you have provided. Hope this helps.

```
private bool moveLeft, moveRight;

void Start ()
{
    // Get Rigidbody or CC or whatever you use to move your object.
}

void Update ()
{
    if (moveLeft)
    {
        // Move Left
        Debug.Log("Moving Left");
    }
}

public void MoveLeft()
{
    moveLeft = true;
}

public void StopMovingLeft()
{
    moveLeft = false;
}
```

EDIT: Very important - I just saw that you are using transform.position += Vector3 to move the object. You will have big troubles with accurate collision, as your function is literally teleporting your gameobject to the new position. To avoid bad colliding you should use Rigidbody.AddForce or if you want to use transform you can easily use transform.Translate:

From Unity Docs:
transform.Translate(Vector3.forward * Time.deltaTime);

EDIT 2: Here is the code you have requested in the comment to this answer. Just copy the script, should work fine.

```
private bool moveLeft, moveRight;

// Create the rigidbody and the collider
private Rigidbody rb;
private Collider col;

// Create a variable you can change in inspector window for speed
[SerializeField]
private float speed;

void Start ()
{
    // You can either use a CC (Character Controller) or a Rigidbody. Doesn't make that much of a difference.
    // Important thing is, if you use a rigidbody, you will need a collider as well. Collider detect collision
    // but rigidbodies do the actual work with regards to physics. In this case we use rigidbody/collider

    // Get the rigidbody
    // If you are making a 2D game, you should use Rigidbody2D
    // The rigidbody will simulate actual physics. I tested this script, the 
    // rigibody will accelerate and will need time to slow down upon breaking
    // You can change it's mass and stuff
    rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();

    // Now in this case we just get any collider. You can be more specific, if you know which collider your gameobjects has
    // e.g. BoxCollider or SphereCollider
    // If you are making a 2D game, you should use Collider2D
    col = GetComponent<Collider>();
}


void Update ()
{
    if (moveLeft)
    {
        // If you make a 2D game, use Vector2
        rb.AddForce(Vector3.left * speed);
    }
}

public void MoveLeft()
{
    moveLeft = true;
}

public void StopMovingLeft()
{
    moveLeft = false;
}
```

Comment: Hi and thank you. How do I get the rididbody or "CC"? thank you

Comment: I will edit the answer to this new question into my old answer. Just give me a minute.

Comment: Hey great, thank you! But what I dont understand is, when I attach this script to my button - how will it find the RigidBody of my character? These are two different game objects, arent they?

Comment: Hey there, you have to attach the script to your Game Object you want to move, e.g. your Character or a Cube or whatever. The buttons don't need actual scripts. Just do the same I did in the screenshot with the buttons, that's all they need.

Comment: It was a pleasure to help you!

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this. In your script, attached to a button:

```
using UnityEngine.EventSystems; // Required when using Event data.

public class ExampleClass : MonoBehaviour, IPointerDownHandler // required interface when using the OnPointerDown method.
{
    bool moveLeft = false;

    // Do this when the mouse is clicked over the selectable object this script is attached to.
    public void OnPointerDown(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        moveLeft = true;
        Debug.Log(this.gameObject.name + " was clicked.");
    }

    public void OnPointerUp(PointerEventData eventData) 
    {
        moveLeft = false;
        Debug.Log(this.gameObject.name + " was released.");
    }

    void Update() 
    {
        if (moveLeft)
             // Move left code
    }
}
```

This is a fairly dumb example, but should be at least something you can expand on.